# Problem redefinning command{\<}?

Tags: macros

I have a problem with redefine the command `\<`

```
\documentclass{article}  
  \renewcommand{\<}{\left\langle\!\left\langle}
 \renewcommand{\>}{\right\rangle\!\right\rangle}
  \begin{document}
 $\< qs \> $
\end{document}
```

The compilation gives me notice that me dvi file is ok. Anyone has an idea?

```
  Running `LaTeX' on `tot' with ``latex  -interaction=nonstopmode "\input" tot.tex''
 This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
 entering extended mode
 LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>
 Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english, usenglishmax,    dumylang, nohyphenation, french, basque, loaded.
  (./tot.tex (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/article.cls
  Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))

  ! LaTeX Error: \<undefined.

  See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
  Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
  ...                                              

 l.3  \renewcommand{\<}
                  {\left\langle\!\left\langle}
  (./tot.aux) [1] (./tot.aux) )
  (see the transcript file for additional information)
  Output written on tot.dvi (1 page, 336 bytes).
  Transcript written on tot.log.

  LaTeX exited abnormally with code 1 at Tue Sep 24 14:59:35
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`\<` is not predefined.

```
\documentclass{article}  
\newcommand{\<}{\left\langle\!\left\langle}
\renewcommand{\>}{\right\rangle\!\right\rangle}
\begin{document}
 $\< qs \> $
\end{document}
```

Note: `\>` is predefined as a math skip in LaTeX2e.

Answer (score 12):

I think you have located a LaTeX bug.

The error message should have been

```
! LaTeX Error: \< undefined.
```

If you use a normal command name with letters you do get a space.

```
\renewcommand\wibble{aaa}
```

produces

```
! LaTeX Error: \wibble undefined.
```

Interestingly LaTeX 2.09 got this right but we broke it while saving some tokens.

The current definition is

```
\def\renew@command#1{%
  \begingroup \escapechar\m@ne\xdef\@gtempa{{\string#1}}\endgroup
  \expandafter\@ifundefined\@gtempa
     {\@latex@error{\noexpand#1undefined}\@ehc}%
     \relax
  \let\@ifdefinable\@rc@ifdefinable
  \new@command#1}
```

it should be

```
\def\renew@command#1{%
  \begingroup \escapechar\m@ne\xdef\@gtempa{{\string#1}}\endgroup
  \expandafter\@ifundefined\@gtempa
     {\@latex@error{\string#1 undefined}\@ehc}%
     \relax
  \let\@ifdefinable\@rc@ifdefinable
  \new@command#1}
```

Probably the one extra byte of memory can be afforded these days.

The LaTeX2.09 definition didn't have this problem:

```
\def\renewcommand#1{\edef\@tempa{\expandafter\@cdr\string
  #1\@nil}\@ifundefined{\@tempa}{\@latexerr{\string#1\space undefined}\@ehc
    }{}\@ifnextchar [{\@reargdef#1}{\@reargdef#1[0]}}
```

But it did have the other problem that you could not redefine `\@tempa`.

```
%    Reorganised slightly so that |\renewcommand{\reserved@a}[1]{foo}|
%    works.  I am not sure this is worth it, as a following
%    |\newcommand| would over-write the definition of |\reserved@a|.
%    
%    Recall that \LaTeX2.09 goes into an infinite loop with
%    |\renewcommand[1]{\@tempa}{foo}| (DPC 6 October 93).
%
```

The subsequent change to remove a space seems suspect

```
% \changes{LaTeX2e}{1993/11/23}{Macro reimplemented and extended}
% \changes{v1.1f}{1994/05/2}{Removed surplus \cs{space} in error}
%    \begin{macrocode}
```

Answer (score 6):

The clue is in the error message:

> `! LaTeX Error: \<undefined.`

You can't use `\renewcommand` for undefined commands.

`\<` is only defined in the `tabbing` environment. So you'd need to use `\newcommand` rather than `\renewcommand`. However, if you use `tabbing` (or you use any code that uses `tabbing` in its definition), you'll encounter problems.

Comment: I try \newcommand and it does not work. I get


Command \> already defined.
Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                               
l.5 ...ewcommand{\>}{\right\rangle\!\right\rangle}

Comment: @etienne You have to say `\newcommand\<{...}` and `\renewcommand\>{...}`, because `\<` is undefined, but `\>` is defined. However, I can't recommend defining/redefining either of them.